# Minimum Shift Keying

Tags: signal, signal-processing, signal-theory

"Overall frequency excursion del-f in MSK  is *minimum frequency spacing* between symbols 0 and 1 that allows their FSK representation to be coherently orthogonal". What is meant by being *coherently orthogonal* here?

Comment: Duplicate question https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/orthogonality-of-fsk-modulation-for-non-coherent-detection

Answer (score -1):

Orthogonal means the cross-correlations are Zero, for ideal symbols.

Coherently orthogonal places a requirement on the phasing.